# Existence of smooth function which has compact support

Tags: real-analysis, functions, partial-differential-equations, special-functions

Assume we have two sets $V,W$, for which $V \subset \subset W \subset \subset \Omega  \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ holds. Now we want to find a **smooth** function $\psi$, such that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\psi \equiv 1 \text{ in } V, \\
\psi \equiv 0 \text{ in } \mathbb{R}^n \setminus W, \\
\psi \in [0,1].
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
holds.

How do we know that such a function exists? That problem occured to me in a proof in Chapter 6 of L. Evans' Book "Partial differential equations".

Comment: Search for 'bump functions'. You can look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BumpFunction.html

Comment: This follows from Urysohn Lemma. Your sets $V$ and $\mathbb{R}^n-W$ are separated, since $V$ is compactly contained in the open set $W$ so there is room for such a function to exist. You can see the proof, for ex. on Wikipedia.

Comment: What does $\subset \subset $ mean? And what is $\Omega $ ?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet it usually mean

Comment: $\subset \subset$ means a compact subset. 
Thanks @GReyes, that fully answered my question! :)